# Is Azure AD Conditional Access supported for Client Credential Flow authentication?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have successfully configured an Azure AD conditional access policy to IP restrict access to an application for all users. I am however not able to get the same working for a daemon application using client credential flow authentication. Does Azure AD conditional access policies only work for user authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. It can only works for user interface authentication.

First, Conditional Access has some requirements:

You can use Azure AD conditional access to protect cloud apps when an authentication attempt comes from:

> - A web browser
> - A client app that uses modern authentication
> - Exchange ActiveSync

About A client app that users modern authentication: This is based on ADAL. So, it also needs user sign in.